# Как настроить Apache после изменения архитектуры проекта?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Нужно было внедрить несложный дополнительный функционал на старом самописном сайте. Это потребовало установки нескольких библиотек через composer. После такой модернизации архитектура проекта выглядит так:

```
/site.ru/
    index.php
    /config/
    /class/
    /templates/
    /images/
    /css/
    /js/
    /controller/
        catalog.php
        news.php
        router.php
        …
    vendor/
    composer.lock
    composer.json
```

Document root веб-сервера — `/site.ru/www/`, соответственно, и папка vendor, и конфигурационные файлы composer попадают в публичный доступ, что небезопасно.

Я попробовал создать папку public, перенести в нее файл index.php, а также папки с шаблонами, картинками, стилями и скриптами, а затем сменить Document root в настройках Apache на `/site.ru/www/public/`. В скриптах обновил пути. Структура стала такой:

```
/site.ru/
    /public/
        index.php
        /templates/
        /images/
        /css/
        /js/
    /config/
    /class/
    /controller/
        catalog.php
        news.php
        router.php
        …
    /vendor/
    composer.lock
    composer.json
```

В итоге рабочей осталась только главная страница сайта, при попытке открыть какую-нибудь из внутренних страниц получаю 500 Internal Server Error. Вероятно, дело в настройках Apache, но я пока не понимаю в каких, т.к. плохо с ним знаком.

Конечно, вместо изменения структуры можно пойти более простым путем — запретить доступ к папке `/vendor/` и файлам `composer.lock`, `composer.json` через `.htaccess` (как это описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766175/hide-composer-vendor-folder-thats-inside-docroot)), но хочется найти решение с более безопасной структурой.

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: Так смотрите ошибки PHP, у Вас должен апач в логах выдавать причину падения. Смотрите, что конкретно не так

Comment: надо открыть логи пхп/апача и посмотреть, что именно вызывает ошибку 503. Очевидно само по себе там в загрузке require файлов путь `./controller/catalog.php` не поменяется на `../controller/catalog.php`. Хорошо если все сделано через какую-нить константу а-ля `BASE_DIR` кототый можно быстро исправить и на этом все закончится.

Comment: Ошибка в логах: [core:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:50441] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://site.ru/